# count values with yes and not in sql statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

I have a table with data like this:

```
 USER  NAME     Timestamp               EXECUTED    CLOSED
1 user1 JOHN DOE 2015-11-23 12:50:45         Yes       Yes
2 user1 JOHN DOE 2015-11-23 12:52:35         Yes       Yes
3 user1 JOHN DOE 2015-11-23 12:53:52         Yes       Yes
4 user1 JOHN DOE 2015-11-23 12:54:59         Yes       Yes
5 user1 JOHN DOE 2015-11-23 12:56:04         Yes       Yes
6 user1 JOHN DOE 2015-11-23 18:09:37         Yes       No
7 user1 JOHN DOE 2015-11-23 18:15:46         Yes       Yes
8 user1 JOHN DOE 2015-11-23 18:17:02         Yes       Yes
```

And i want to prepare a report like this:

```
USER   NAME      EXECUTED  CLOSED  NOTCLOSED
user1  JOHN DOE    8         7         1
```

I tried with something like this:

```
SELECT USER, NAME, Timestamp, count(EXECUTED), count(CLOSED) 
FROM table 
WHERE Timestamp LIKE "2015-11-23%" 
AND EXECUTED = "Yes" 
AND CLOSED = "Yes"
```

But the result in this case ever shows:

```
EXECUTED    CLOSED
8           8
```

When i have 1 record with Closed = No.
I know that when i count the columns EXECUTED and CLOSED i can't eval properly with a WHERE = YES/NO because the datatype change to integer, but i can't find a proper solution.

Other thing: How i can show the proper value to "NO CLOSE" column? (difference between EXECUTED and CLOSED)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select user, name,
    sum(case when executed = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as executed,
    sum(case when closed = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as closed,
    sum(case when executed = 'Yes' and closed = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) as notclosed
from user
group by user, name
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```
;WITH counts AS (
    SELECT USER
          ,NAME
          ,Timestamp
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXECUTED = "YES" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumExecuted
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN CLOSED = "YES" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumClosed
    FROM table 
    WHERE Timestamp LIKE "2015-11-23%" 
)
SELECT USER
      ,NAME
      ,Timestamp
      ,NumExecuted
      ,NumClosed
      ,NumExecuted - NumClosed AS NumOpen
FROM counts
```

Comment: Why are you putting a semicolon in front of the WITH?

Comment: COUNT() counts all non-NULL values, so it will happily count the `0` values, too. You'd need NULLs, or a different aggregation function.

Comment: @CL  Yes, of course.  I meant SUM, not COUNT (edited).  I added the semicolon out of habit to make sure any previous statements are terminated before starting the CTE (common table expression).  Completely unnecessary in this example, though.

Comment: Then why leave it there (and omit the terminating semicolon)?

Comment: See this response to the same question by Aaron Bertrand: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23374